# Editing in Library versus List

Tags: permissions, library

I have a document library that I have to limit access to read only for my users but also have a list that I need them to be able to make edits. I made a change to the site visitors, currently the NT Users who are within the company, to only allow view only. This resulted in keeping them from making edits to the reports in the document library but it removed the edit access they had to my list. Is there a way to do this without restricting access to both? I though the lists and libraries were separate. TIA

Answer (score 3):

To achieve your requirement, you would:

1. [Break permissions inheritance](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/customize-permissions-for-a-sharepoint-list-or-library-02d770f3-59eb-4910-a608-5f84cc297782) on the list
2. Change the "Site Visitor" group access on the list from read only to contribute

This assumes your permissions levels are still the default (Read, Contribute, Full Control, etc.).